# "IN" clause in LINQ to Entities with 2 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In my SQL, I am joining 2 tables to collect this data, which I am getting the desired result set :

```
 select * from [Website] as A
        inner join [OrderToWebsite] as B
        on A.WebsiteId = b.WebsiteId
        where B.OrderId in (25, 26, 29, 32)
```

In my VS, I am collecting the items (25,26,29,32) via :

```
var orderIDs = (List<int>)Session["OrderIds"];
```

I am stuck writing the same T-SQL query using LINQ,  I have tried so far :

```
 IEnumerable<Website> model = from A in _db.Websites
                                     join B in _db.OrderToWebsites
                                     on A.WebsiteId equals B.WebsiteId
                                     .........(Not sure how to include the orderIDs to check against...)
                                     select B.OrderId.tolist();
```

This was closed earlier as repeated question, but this situation is unique and I couldn't find an answer for this type of scenario.

OrderToWebsiteiewModel.cs

```
public class OrderToWebsiteiewModel
{
    public int OrderToWebsiteId{ get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; } 
    public int WebsiteId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerAgrreementId { get; set; } 
    public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

WebsiteViewModel.cs

```
 public class WebsiteViewModel
{
    public int WebsiteId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string URL { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? WebsiteAvailableBeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WebsiteAvailableEndDate { get; set; } 
    public bool? ProposedWebsite { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your model. It is important to check which navigation properties do you have.

Comment: Which model would you like to see ? I have viewmodels and my data entity models

Comment: Your classes `Website` and `OrderToWebsite`

Comment: updated my question with both the viewmodel classes

Comment: Not ViewModel ( Classes that used to access to Database.

Comment: @GertArnold, tried to focus that there are navigation properties before pointing to Contains ;)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv, I am using viewmodel to access my data objects

Comment: @Gert Arnold, re-read my posts so you would get a clear understanding of what I am trying to achieve versus what's out there. I know .Contains does the job for other scenarios, but doesnt work for my query.

Comment: from A in _db.Websites
                                         join B in _db.OrderToWebsites
                                         on A.WebsiteId equals B.WebsiteId
                                         where B.OrderId.Contains   gives a squiggly , this is what I am trying to explain in my post @Gert Arnold

Comment: `where orderIDs.Contains(B.OrderId)` is your answer.